# How can I get jQuery code working on touch screen device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use some jQuery code for my range slider, it works well on PC but not working on a touch device and I don't know how to fix it.

I have tried different ways such as:

_ Use  `on('touchmove', rangeInputChangeEventHandler);` instead of `on('input', rangeInputChangeEventHandler);` but it still not working

_ Add `$('input[type="range"]').on( 'touchstart', rangeInputChangeEventHandler);` below `$('input[type="range"]').on( 'input', rangeInputChangeEventHandler);` line and it's still not working.

Here is my code, it includes Javascript, jQuery, HTML, and CSS to run code:

Javascript

```js
//main function change number of slider when dragging
(function() {
  // function to round up number
  function lamtronTien(number) {
    // set rounded, currentForamt, tienFormat as varibale
    var rounded = Math.round(number / 1000000) * 1000000;
    var currentFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("vn-VN");
    var tienFormat = currentFormat.format(rounded);
    //
    return tienFormat;
  }

  //function to turn number into word
  function docSoTien(number) {
    // replace "," with ""
    number = number.replaceAll(",", "");
    // set variable ty and trieu as below
    var ty = Math.pow(10, 9);
    var trieu = Math.pow(10, 6);
    // when number = 0 return 0
    if (number === "0") {
      return 0;
      // else number is larger than ty
    } else {
      if (number >= ty) {
        // set variable as floor of "number" devided by "ty"
        var hangTy = Math.floor(number / ty);
        // if hangTy is greater than 1 then result
        if (hangTy >= 1) {
          // set varibales
          var hangTrieu = number % ty;
          var hangTrieu = Math.floor(hangTrieu / trieu);
          if (hangTrieu > 0) {
            return (hangTy + " Tỷ " + hangTrieu + " Triệu");
            // else
          } else {
            return (hangTy + " Tỷ");
          }
        }

      } else {
        // var hangTrieu = number % ty;
        var hangTrieu = Math.floor(number / trieu);
        if (hangTrieu > 0) {
          return (hangTrieu + " Triệu");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // function to apply change when there is a change in number input
  function rangeInputChangeEventHandler(e) {
    // set attribute name as rangeGroup
    var rangeGroup = $(this).attr('name'),

      minBtn = $(this).parent().children('.min'),
      maxBtn = $(this).parent().children('.max'),
      // get value of range_min, range_max
      range_min = $(this).parent().children('.range_min'),
      range_max = $(this).parent().children('.range_max'),
      minVal = parseInt($(minBtn).val()),
      maxVal = parseInt($(maxBtn).val()),
      origin = e.originalEvent.target.className;
    // if origin 
    if (origin === 'min' && minVal > maxVal - 5) {
      $(minBtn).val(maxVal - 5);
    }
    var minVal = parseInt($(minBtn).val());
    $(range_min).html(docSoTien(lamtronTien(minVal)));

    // if origin is max and maxVal minus 5 is smaller than minVal
    if (origin === 'max' && maxVal - 5 < minVal) {
      $(maxBtn).val(5 + minVal);
    }
    var maxVal = parseInt($(maxBtn).val());
    if (docSoTien(lamtronTien(maxVal)) === '3 Tỷ') {
      $(range_max).html('> 3 Tỷ');
    } else {
      // apply to range_max
      $(range_max).html(docSoTien(lamtronTien(maxVal)));
    };
  }

  // apply change to input type range
  $('input[type="range"]').on('input', rangeInputChangeEventHandler);


})();
```

```css
/* adjust */

input[type='range'] {
  width: 210px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}


/* adjust */

input[type='range'],
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track,
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
}


/* adjust */

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #003D7C;
}


/* adjust */

input[type='range']:nth-child(2)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: none;
}


/* adjust */

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #003D7C;
  border-radius: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* adjust */

input[type='range']:nth-child(1)::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
}

.rangeslider {
  height: 60px;
  width: 210px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}


/* adjust rangeslider input */

.rangeslider input {
  position: absolute;
}


/* adjust rangeslider  */

.rangeslider {
  position: absolute;
}


/* adjust rangeslider span*/

.rangeslider span {
  margin-top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}


/* adjust rangeslider right thumb  */

.rangeslider .right {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -70px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<!-- slider -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- slider -->
<div class="slider-group">
  <div class="rangeslider">
    <input class="min" name="min" type="range" min="0" max="3000000000" value="0" />
    <input class="max" name="max" type="range" min="0" max="3000000000" value="3000000000" />
    <span class="range_min light left">0</span>
    <span class="range_max light right"> > 3 Tỷ</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my site: [link](http://35.187.250.171/)
Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Please post RENDERED HTML without server templating

Comment: Also you are missing functions like `docSoTien` and `lamtronTien`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=type%3Drange+mobile+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan I add the full code to make it work. Hope you can help me solve the problem. Thank you!